# emerge only prints it's parameters along with "Wrong gcc version" message

Tags: gcc, gentoo

**Our gentoo server has been left in inconsistent state. I don't know what have been done wrong previously, but now I need to fix the system somehow.

I've tried to do revdep-rebuild, but it has failed:**

...
x11-libs/gksu:0
x11-libs/gtk+:2
x11-libs/gtkglarea:2
x11-libs/libgksu:2
x11-libs/libsvg-cairo:0
x11-libs/qt-gui:4
..........

- IMPORTANT: 12 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
- Use eselect news to read news items.

Calculating dependencies... done!

emerge: there are no ebuilds to satisfy "gnome-base/gswitchit-plugins:0".

emerge: searching for similar names...
emerge: Maybe you meant any of these: gnome-base/gswitchit-plugins, gnome-extra/gswitchit-plugins, gnome-base/nautilus?

- IMPORTANT: 12 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
- Use eselect news to read news items.
- revdep-rebuild failed to emerge all packages.
- you have the following choices:
- - If emerge failed during the build, fix the problems and re-run revdep-rebuild.
- - Use /etc/portage/package.keywords to unmask a newer version of the package.
- (and remove 5_order.rr to be evaluated again)
- - Modify the above emerge command and run it manually.
- - Compile or unmerge unsatisfied packages manually,
- remove temporary files, and try again.
- (you can edit package/ebuild list first)
- To remove temporary files, please run:
- rm /var/cache/revdep-rebuild/*.rr

**I've tried to remove one of the mentioned packages:**

harley ~ # emerge -C gswitchit-plugins
Wrong gcc version = echo -C gswitchit-plugins
harley ~ #

**I don't see any problems with the gcc, but emerge isn't working:**

harley ~ # gcc --version
gcc (Gentoo 4.5.2 p1.0, pie-0.4.5) 4.5.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

harley ~ # gcc-config -l
 [1] i686-pc-linux-gnu-3.3.6
 [2] i686-pc-linux-gnu-3.4.6
 [3] i686-pc-linux-gnu-3.4.6-hardened
 [4] i686-pc-linux-gnu-3.4.6-hardenednopie
 [5] i686-pc-linux-gnu-3.4.6-hardenednopiessp
 [6] i686-pc-linux-gnu-3.4.6-hardenednossp
 [7] i686-pc-linux-gnu-4.1.2
 [8] i686-pc-linux-gnu-4.5.2 *
harley ~ # emerge --help
Wrong gcc version = echo --help
harley ~ # which emerge
/root/bin/emerge
harley ~ # emerge
Wrong gcc version = echo
harley ~ # emerge fdslkgj
Wrong gcc version = echo fdslkgj
harley ~ #

**How can I fix emerge?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# cat /root/bin/emerge  
#!/bin/sh   echo "Wrong gcc version = echo $@"   gcc -v 2>&1 | grep "gcc
version 4.3.1" || exit 1  
/usr/bin/emerge $@
```

Looks like it was necessary to have gcc of version 4.3.1 selected.